# how to upload data from excel using association in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models called dealer, city and state in which I have one to many relationship between dealer and city. Secondly, there is a one to many relationship between city and state:

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :dealers
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end
```

In the dealers_controller.rb I have a method:

```
 def import
    Dealer.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to dealers_path, notice: "Products imported."
  end
```

Which will refer the method in dealer model:

```
def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
     city = City.new
     state = State.new
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      dealer = find_by_id(row["id"].to_i) || new
      dealer.dealerName = row["DEALERSHIPNAME"]
      dealer.address = row["ADDRESS"]
      dealer.pincode = row["PINCODE"]
      city.name = row["CITY"]
      state.name = row["STATE"]
      dealer.phoneNo = row["PHONENO"]
      dealer.mobileNo = row["MOBILE"]
      city.save!
      state.save!
      dealer.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when '.xls' then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
    when '.xlsx' then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

The problem is the dealer data is being stored in dealer table perfectly but the city and state is being stored once that is only last record and city_id in dealer table is null and state_id in city table is also null.

How do I upload whole data of city and state in city and state table using this dealer model?

How we can upload excel file which will populate all three tables which are in one to many associations?

Comment: here i need to create new object for every city and state row

Answer (score 0):

```
i was creating the city and states object once outside of the loop but its instance must be created for every row which is coming from excel sheet, stores states unique and stores city according to states  


  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)

    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      dealer = find_by_id(row["id"].to_i) || new
      dealer.dealerName = row["DEALERSHIPNAME"]
      dealer.address = row["ADDRESS"]
      dealer.pincode = row["PINCODE"]
      dealer.phoneNo = row["PHONENO"]
      dealer.mobileNo = row["MOBILE"]
      stateName = row["STATE"]
      state = State.where(:name=>stateName).first
      state_id = state.id unless state.nil?
      name = row["CITY"]
      city = City.where(:name=>name).first
      city_id = city.id unless city.nil?
      if state.nil?
        stateObj = State.new
        stateObj.name = stateName
        stateObj.save!
         if city.nil?
        cityObj = City.new
        cityObj.name = name
        cityObj.state_id = stateObj.id
        cityObj.save!
        dealer.city_id = cityObj.id
        dealer.save!
        else
        cityObj = City.new
        cityObj.name = city.name
        cityObj.state_id = stateObj.id
        cityObj.save!
        dealer.city_id = cityObj.id
        dealer.save!
        end
      else
        if city.nil?
        cityObj = City.new
        cityObj.name = name
        cityObj.state_id = state.id
        cityObj.save!
        dealer.city_id = cityObj.id
        dealer.save!
        else
        unless City.where(:name=>name).map{|c|c.state_id}.include? state.id
        cityObj = City.new
        cityObj.name = city.name
        cityObj.state_id = state.id
          cityObj.save!
        dealer.city_id = cityObj.id
        dealer.save!
        else
        dealer.city_id =  City.where(:name=>name,:state_id =>state.id).first.id
        dealer.save!
        end
        end
      end
  end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when '.xls' then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
    when '.xlsx' then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
    end
```